# Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal shows the OneDrive folder eroneously

Tags: c#, environment-variables

Win 11. C# Visual Studio 22 Version 17.5.0 Preview 5.0

I have uninstalled OneDrive. File Explorer show "Documents" as C:\Users\Mike\Documents but Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal (or .MyDocuments) returns C:\Users\Mike\OneDrive\Documents.

How can I resolve this?

Mike.

I tried to set a string to the "Documents" folder but got the "OneDrive\Documents" folder.

Comment: It sounds like that's a discrepancy between what's set for your Documents library and Documents "folder". You can make the "Documents" folder point to something else with these instructions: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-save-location-windows-10
What do you mean by "I tried to set a string to the "Documents" folder but got the "OneDrive\Documents" folder."?